# Show the Cartesian product $N\times H$ is a group with operation $(n,h)*(n',h')=(n\alpha_h(n'),hh')$

Tags: group-theory, abstract-algebra

**Given**: If $G$ is a group with normal subgroup $N$ and subgroup $H$ such that $G=NH$ and $N\cap H=\{e\}$, then $G$ is called a semidirect product of $N$ by $H$.

Let Aut$(N)$ be the automorphism group of $N$.

I have shown that if $G$ is a semidirect product of $N$ by $H$, then the map $\alpha:H\rightarrow$ Aut$(N)$, given by $\alpha(h)=\alpha_h$, where $\alpha_h(n)=hnh^{-1}$, is a homomorphism.

**Question**: Show that if $N$ and $H$ are groups and $h\mapsto\alpha_h$ is a homomorphism $H\rightarrow$ Aut $(N)$, then the Cartesian product $N\times H$ is a group with group operation $$(n,h)*(n',h')=(n\alpha_h(n'),hh')$$

[To check the group axioms it is enough to check associvity $e*x=x\forall x\in X$ and $\forall x\in X,\exists x^{-1}\in X$ s.t. $x*x^{-1}=e$]

**Answer**:

**(Associavity)**: Show for $n^1,n^2,n^3\in N$, $h^1,h^2,h^3\in H$.

$[(n^1,h^1)*(n^2,h^2)]*(n^3,h^3)=(n^1,h^1)*[(n^2,h^2)*(n^3,h^3)]$

LHS: $[(n^1,h^1)*(n^2,h^2)]*(n^3,h^3)=(n^1\alpha_{h^1}(n^2),h^1h^2)=(n^1\alpha_{h^1}(n^2)\alpha_{h^1h^2}(n^3),h^1h^2h^3)$

RHS: $(n^1,h^1)*[(n^2,h^2)*(n^3,h^3)]=(n^1,h^1)*(n^2\alpha_{h^2}(n^3),h^2h^3)=(n^1\alpha_{h^1}(n^2\alpha_{h^2}(n^3)),h^1h^2h^3)$

Therefore we need to show: $\alpha_{h^1}(n^2)\alpha_{h^1h^2}(n^3)=\alpha_{h^1}(n^2\alpha_{h^2}(n^3))$.

Since $\alpha_h$ is a homomorphism, we have:

$\alpha_{h^1}(n^2\alpha_{h^2}(n^3))=\alpha_{h^1}(n^2)\alpha_{h^1}(\alpha_{h^2}(n^3))=\alpha_{h^1}(n^2)\alpha_{h^1h^2}(n^3)$

**(Identity)**: Take $e\in N$ and $e'\in H$ as the identity in $N$ and $H$ respectively.

Then $(e,e')*(n,h)=(e\alpha_{e'}(n),e'h)$

$e\alpha_{e'}(n)=ee'n(e')^{-1}=n$ and $e'h=h$, so $(e,e')*(n,h)=(n,h)$, so the identity in $N\times H$ exists and is $(e,e')$

**(Inverse)**: Show $(n,h)*(n,h)^{-1}=(e,e')$ for some $(n,h)^{-1}\in N\times H$

Let $(n,h)^{-1}=(n',h')$. Then $(n,h)*(n',h')=(n\alpha_h(n'),hh')$

Are there $n'\in N$ and $h'\in H$ such that $(n\alpha_h(n'),hh')=(e,e')$?

We have $n\alpha_h(n')=e$ and $hh'=e'$

For the first one we have $nhn'h^{-1}=e$, the second one we have $h'=h^{-1}$ so $h'\in H$

**Point of contention**: Stuck as to what we should do to the first one to show that $n'$ exists in $N$.

I'm so close to the end and the answer is probably going to be very simple, but I would be very grateful if I could get help with showing the existence of the inverse in the group.

Comment: if $N$ and $H$ are two different groups, then what is the meaning of $hnh^{-1}$? definitely *something* is missing.

Comment: the second question does make sense though

Comment: @Krish Thanks for pointing that out, this was the last part to a question, will add more to the start to make sure it makes sense

Comment: @Krish, done, let me know if there is any other missing information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For given $(n, h) \in N \times H,$ we need to find $(n', h') \in N \times H$ such that $(n, h) * (n', h') = (e, e) = (n', h') * (n, h).$

$(e,e) = (n, h)*(n', h') = (n \alpha_h(n'), hh') \Rightarrow n \alpha_h(n') = e, hh' = e \Rightarrow nhn'h^{-1} = e, h' = h^{-1}.$ Now $nhn'h^{-1} = e \Rightarrow n' = h^{-1}n^{-1}h \in G.$ Since $N$ is normal in $G, h^{-1}n^{-1}h \in N.$ On the other hand, $n' \alpha_{h'}(n) = n'h'nh'^{-1} = h^{-1}n^{-1}h h^{-1}nh = e.$ So $(h^{-1}n^{-1}h, h^{-1})$ is an inverse of $(n, h).$

Comment: Ah, very clever, did not think to use the fact the $N$ is normal in $G$. Thanks very much for this answer

Comment: @Dansmith: you are welcome. one more fact: the identity element of $N \times H$ is $(e, e)$ where  $e$ is the identity element of $G.$ you shouldn't write $(e, e').$ (and please write $h_1, n_1, \cdots$ instead of $h^1, n^1, \cdots$ as superscript mostly stands for taking "powers".)

Comment: Thanks, I wouldn't have realised this and I will use subscripts in future.